# What is the best free JavaScript obfuscator that is available as a Java library?

Tags: java, javascript, ant, obfuscation

I know this question has been asked many times, but here are my specific needs. The obfuscator needs to come in a form of a java library, so I can make an Ant task in order to automate the build process. IE7, 8, Firefox and Chrome must be able to interpret the resulting js very fast (original js file is pretty big - 18k lines of code). If none exist which satisfy these requirements I'm willing to consider a commercial solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some options:

- [YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/).  See [Julien Lecomte's blog](http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/09/16/) for example use from Ant.
- LCA Soft provide a free [Ant task](http://www.lcasoft.com/compress-js-doc.html) interface to the [Dojo Toolkit](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/) compressor.
- [Jawr](https://jawr.java.net/) - [Ant task](https://jawr.java.net/docs/jawr_ant_task.html).

(I've not used Jawr or Dojo, so can't comment on which is best.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. YUI does a fine job, but do you know of any obfuscators that do a Base64 mixing (all the requirements mentioned above must still apply)?

Comment: ... like the one on this page jsutility.pjoneil.net (problems: apart from not being a jar, it's slow on IE7)

Comment: I accepted your answer since ScriptMixer is no longer available as a download (I still use it though :-)).

Comment: As far as I know YUI compressor don't obfuscate code, it just minify

Answer (score 3):

Google's [closure-compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) is another alternative.

Answer (score 1):

There is a newer free option for Javascript Obfuscation - [Roquson](http://roquson.com). They provide completely free Javascript Obfuscation with additional features like Variable renaming, Domain Locking and Expiration Date.

Check it out here: http://roquson.com

Comment: Outdated, project seems discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

I still believe that jsutility.pjoneil.net provides the best compression of any program available except for gzip.   It's obfuscation support is avoids most of the problems with obfuscation.   It also now support batch operations.